# Why AngularJs 2 supports bootstrapping only through code

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, server-side-rendering, ng-app

In AngularJs 1 there were two ways of bootstrapping your module.

- Automatic by ng-app
- Manual bootstrap by code

But now when I started exploring Angular 2 I can find only one way of bootstraping it (through code).When I investigated more I found that this has been restricted because of security reasons, as well as architectural changes.

> You instantiate an Angular application by explicitly specifying a
>   component to use as the root component for your application via the
>   bootstrap() method.
>       An application is bootstrapped inside an existing browser DOM, typically index.html. Unlike Angular 1, Angular 2 does not 
>    compile/process providers in index.html. This is mainly for security
>   reasons, as well as architectural changes in Angular 2. This means
>   that index.html can safely be processed using server-side technologies
>   such as providers.

**Note**: Found above statement from **platform_browser_dynamic.js**

**Questions:**

1. What security reasons were there to remove automatic bootstrapping.
2. What problems automatic bootstrapping was creating for server side rendering.